# Any good SQL Anywhere database schema comparison tools?

Tags: sql, comparison, schema, sqlanywhere

Are there any good database schema comparison tools out there that support Sybase SQL Anywhere version 10?  I've seen a litany of them for SQL Server, a few for MySQL and Oracle, but nothing that supports SQL Anywhere correctly.

I tried using DB Solo, but it turned all my non-unique indexes into unique ones, and I didn't see any options to change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to download SQL Anywhere Version 11, and Compare It!, check out the comparison technique shown here:

http://sqlanywhere.blogspot.com/2008/08/comparing-database-schemas.html

You don't have to upgrade your SQL Anywhere Version 10 database.

Comment: I've done that, and in fact, that's the method I'm using right now.  It would be much easier, however, if there was a tool similar to apps such as SQL Data Compare and SQL Delta that supported SQL Anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The new kid on the block is [Qwerybuilder](http://www.werysoft.com/Features.aspx). It supports SQL Server, Sybase ASE, Sybase SQL Anywhere and Oracle. I've used it successfully with SQL Anywhere to track schema changes.

Comment: I see the visual difference dialog in it, but do I have to go one by one and compare each object?

Comment: @Lurker - Qwerybuilder will only compare database objects, not the whole build script. If you want to compare whole database schemas,  Breck Carter's answer - dbunload with the -no option - is the way to go. Another is to use PowerDesigner. It can reverse eng. several databases and compare models.

Answer (score 1):

Two I've come across that support SQL Anywhere:

Upscene Database Workbench - http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.sqlanywhere.php

Aquafold - http://www.aquafold.com/index-sybaseany.html

Each one appears has a schema comparison tool, however I have not used either to compare schemas.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLDelta](http://www.sqldelta.com/) is awesome. It is for SQL Server. I've used it with SQL 2000 and 2005. It will compare stored procedures, tables, views, permissions, indexes, etc. It can also compare data between tables I believe. You can sync the changes or generate SQL Scripts for later use. I use it often to script out db changes in development to production.

Ah...missed the Sybase remark. Not sure if SQLDelta can talk to it..but I'd probably give it a shot since Sybase is similar.

Comment: I tried it; no luck, unfortunately.  I've used it for SQL Server, and you're right, it's a great piece of software - I used it to generate SQL update scripts that were used in automatic updates in applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try erwin (CA AllFusion ERwin Data Modeler). It supports quite a lot of different DBs, including SQL Anywhere, and is quite good in reverse/forward engineering and schema comparison. However, you may find it a bit too complex to use for the comparison...

Comment: I took a shot with it; the sybase drivers were ASE only, and with an ODBC connection, it errored out.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) from Red Gate along with [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) the data compare allows you to Compare the contents of two databases and Automatically synchronize your data.
SQL compare allows you to do the same but with the database tables. Nice GUI on each and very easy setup. they also work on a remote database.

There not cheap but each has a 30 trail so you can get a feel if you like it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase PowerDesigner can also Compare or Merge your Database Schema.

It can also Load the Schema from various Databases by ODBC if you have Schema generation Scripts you can also load them into a Model.

Its an expensive tool but great to document and develop you schema changes IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Breck Carter's idea is a good one.  For quick scans, I have an old product that is called DBDelta.  I have it installed on an old Windows 2000 machine because the install I have will not work on an XP machine.  It's a very small app that compares two SQL Anywhere databases across an ODBC connection.

I've done some searches to try and find a later copy, but have not been able to.  The developer was Charles Butcher.  I think he supported it for a while and then stopped back in 2002 or so.

I'll continue to look for a link.  If I find something I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

QweryBuilder 5.5.0 will allow you to compare all procedures, functions, views, tables and triggers in one shot. This release is scheduled for mid May, 2010.

It hasn't been finalized yet but we are also looking at adding an option to turn the diff results into a script that can be executed on a target database.

Comment: If you do the script option, it will be HUGE as far as SQL Anywhere goes.  I haven't found anything at all does this.